# Change jQuery elements into div?

Tags: javascript, html

How to change the window in the `window.changeColour` call Division ID instead of window? Thanks

```
window.changeColour = function(value) {
    switch(value) {
       case 'b':
          color = "#FF0000";
          break;
       case 'r':
          color = "#0000FF";
          break;
       case 'p':
          color = "#FF00FF";
          break;
    }
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

**Here is the HTML:**

```
<div id= "genre"> 
    <br><br> 
    <p> 
        <input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('b')">Blues 
        <br> 
        <input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('r')">Rock 
        <br> 
        <input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('p')">Pop 
        <br>
    </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean get the element with id `Division`, and change it's colour, here's what you get

#### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pm8MM/)

```
var div = document.getElementById("Division")
div.changeColour = function(value)
    {
    switch(value)
     {
        case 'b':
            color = "#FF0000";
        break;
        case 'r':
            color = "#0000FF";
        break;
        case 'p':
            color = "#FF00FF";
        break;
    }
div.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Comment: Why its still not working sir? here is the html of that sir.                   <div id= "genre">

<br>
<br>

<p>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('b')">Blues
<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('r')">Rock
<br>
<input type="radio" name="music" value="radio" onClick="changeColour('p')">Pop
<br>

</div>

Comment: I saw it sir. But when I add the radio button to make choices its not working. Why is that sir?

Comment: Here is what I want to happen sir but I want the color change in a particular division. Thanks Hope you can help me sir ::: http://jsfiddle.net/winresh24/wHBLS/

Comment: Sorry, I ran out of solutions

Comment: Ok, I finally did that. Have a look --> http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/wHBLS/1/